# Python - 2D list of unknown size

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking to create a 2D list to store data .n, I want to store an auto-incrementing ID along side the various pieces of information. The number of rows that will be required is unknown but the number of columns will always be fixed at 6 data values.

I want something like the following:

```
[0, a, b, 1, 2, 3]
[1, c, d, 4, 5, 6]
[2, e, f, 7, 8, 9]
```

I then want to be able to return any of the columns as need, e.g.

```
[a, c, e]
```

At the moment I'm trying the following code:

```
    student_array = []
    student_count = 0
    ...
    Student.student_array.append(Student.student_count)
    Student.student_array.append(name)
    Student.student_array.append(course_name)
    Student.student_array.append(mark_one)
    Student.student_array.append(mark_two)
    Student.student_array.append(mark_three)
    Student.student_count = Student.student_count + 1

def list_students():
    print(Student.student_array[1])
```

The problem I'm having at the moment is that it's obviously appending the new row onto the end of the outer list,  rather than appending a new row. i.e.:

```
[0, 'a', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 1, 'c', 'd', 4, 5, 6]
```

Additionally when it comes to pulling out the second column from each row would the code be along these lines:

```
column_array = []
for row in Student.student_array:
    column_array.append(row[2])
print("Selected Data =", column_array)
```

Comment: When you say 'unknown size' , do you mean unknown size of the 3 lists or unknown number of lists?

Comment: You might want to look at `pandas` here if you're planning on working with tabular data

Comment: If you want to have an array of arrays you should first append items to a temporary array and then append the temp array to the student_array. If you want row and column indexing that's another question. Isn't too difficult but you may want to use something like Pandas.

Comment: *list of lists, to be more Pythonic.

Comment: @mishsx as in I don't know the number of rows that will be needed. The columns will always be a fixed size.

Comment: @Colin747 Then please update that in your query, So what you actually want is a matrix of (unknown rows ) X (6 coloumns ) ?

Comment: @mishsx that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure you have now, with all the data in a single list (list and array mean different things in Python by the way), actually makes it easier to get a column. If your record is of size `r_len = 6`, and you want `col = 3` (the fourth column), you can do

```
>>> Student.student_array[col::r_len]
[1, 4, 7]
```

To store a 2D list, though, you need to place each student's information into a separate list in your loop:

```
current_student = [len(Student.student_array), name, course_name, mark1, mark2, mark3]
Student.student_array.append(current_student)
```

Notice that you do not need to maintain a separate count this way: the length of the outer list speaks for itself.

To get the data from `col = 3` in a 2D array like this, use a comprehension:

```
>>> [s[col] for s in Student.student_array]
[1, 4, 7]
```

Keeping related information in an unlabeled format like that is generally a poor idea though. You can either add labels by using a library like pandas, which will maintain proper tables for you, or you can encapsulate each student's info into a small class. You can write your own class, or use something like a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
Record = collections.namedtuple('Record', ['id', 'name', 'course', 'mark1', 'mark2', 'mark3'])

...

Student.student_array.append(Record(len(Student.student_array), name, course_name, mark1, mark2, mark3))
```

You can now extract `mark1` for each student instead of a numerical index, which is liable to change and cause a maintenance problem later:

```
>>> [s.mark1 for s in Student.student_array]
[1, 4, 7]
```